# How to disable auto-backup for a library project distributed as a third-party SDK?

Tags: android, android-library, aar, android-sharedpreferences

I'm currently working on an android library project (aar) that is meant to be used by third-parties as an SDK.  Internally, I use SharedPreferences to store some data specific to my library:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("my.library.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("my.library.data", "test_data");
editor.apply();
```

On Android Marshmallow and up devices, I notice that even after uninstalling and re-installing the host application (that uses my library), some data that I had previously saved are restored automatically.  Digging through stackoverflow, I find out that on newer devices, the automatic backup restores pretty much everything stored in the private sandbox including SharedPreference files.

What is the most appropriate way to exclude my library's files from the automatic backup behavior, keeping in mind that users of my library may have their own files that they want to be backed up?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not a good answer for this.

You can add `android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"` to the `<application>` tag of your library, just like for an application (as defined [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles)), which will work on its own. However, if the consumer of your library defines their own backup rules, yours will get overwritten during manifest merging.

The way I'd hoped you could do this was to define a string for the path in your library (`<string name="sharedprefs_name">my.library.prefs.xml</string>`), and then tell your consuming application to reference that in their backup rules. Unfortunately, it appears that you can't use a string reference in that file. `<exclude domain="sharedpref" path="@string/sharedprefs_name"/>` doesn't resolve correctly.

The best you can do is hardcode the path in your readme and ask your consumer to exclude it.